# How do I display a QImage in a "functional" programming style

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I want to display an image in a "functional" programming style. Basically, I operate a number of processes on my image and I sometimes want to display the result. So I am trying:

```
int display(string file, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a1(argc,argv);
    QImage myImage;
    myImage.load(file.c_str());
    QLabel myLabel;
    myLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
    myLabel.show();
    return a1.exec();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyImageDataStructure img;
    img.erosion(5);//process 1
    img.save("lenaero.png");
    display("lenaeor.png",argc,argv); // display the first result
    img.dilation(5);//process 2
    img.save("lenaopening.png");
    display("lenaopening.png",argc,argv); // display the second result
    return 1;
}
```

But at the second execution of the display function, an error occurs. Do you have any ideas to solve this problem while keeping this logic?

Thanks

Note: I don't want to include external libraries except Qt and I understand that I want to work outside the Qt logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by "display an image in a `functional` style". I think what you mean is that you want a function to do the display part for an image. In that case, there seems to be a misconception on your part as to what a "functional" paradigm actually is.

Nevertheless, your problem is very different. You need to move the QApplication declaration into the main function:

```
int main(...) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // ...

}
```

And move it out of the `display()` function.

**EDIT**

I re-read your code, and there are a lot of things wrong with it. You SHOULD NOT be creating a separate application every time you wish to display an image. A much better thing would be to use a `QDialog`. Create a dialog, with a label as an image and call `show` on it every time you wish to display the image.

Useful links:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDialog.html

http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/my-first-qt-gui-application.html (Nice overview of creating and showing dialogs)

Comment: Thanks man,

The solution can be this one:

    int display(string file){
        QImage myImage ;
        myImage.load(file.c_str());
        QLabel * myLabel = new QLabel;
        myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
        lay->addWidget(myLabel);
        QDialog * d = new QDialog;
        d->setLayout(lay);
        return d->exec();
    }

Comment: Well, I strongly suggest you don't do that, because you are having a very very bad case of memory leaks. Once the display function exists, you no longer have access to myLabel, lay, d etc. These pointers are destroyed, but the data they point to is not. And after display exits you have absolutely no way of freeing up the memory. I suggest you externally subclass QDialog and do this, or store these pointers and free them when the QDialog exits.

Comment: Or, you can continue using your current solution, but just connect the QDialog's `closed` signal to the `deleteLater` slot of all your other objects like QLayout, QLabel etc.